# Base generic DAO to work with different POJO classes

Tags: java, database

Right now, I have base abstract `GenericDAO` class to execute CRUD operations with different kind of objects. I have Customer and Employee POJO classes which are used in specific `DAO` classes that extends `GenericDAO` class.

**Questions:**

- How correct is the current base `GenericDao` implementation and `SpecificDAO` classes which extend `GenericDAO`?
- Is it a good idea to separate object(i.e. `EmployeeSpecs`, `PersonalSpecs`) properties in separate class where some of them are refereced to specific POJO classes? I did it to use `search()` method easier passing spec object(not by a certain object property) to it.
- How can I implement a search method in the `GenericDAOImpl` abstract class correctly when the `Employee` search method requires 2 arguments (`EmployeeSpecs` and `PersonalSpecs`) and the `Customer` search method requires only one argument (`PersonalSpecs`)?
- How can I implement specs that I can invoke the following `getSpec()` method inside `Customer` or `Employee` classes receiving all specs claases(`PersonalSpecs`, `EmployeeSpecs` if we talk about `Employee` class) applicable for a certain pojo class?

I've read about varargs.  Is it possible to use them with generics that I can put search method inside `GenericDAO` class and can search by multiple object specs?

If you will find that some other places could be optimized or totally improved, please let me know.

**NB!** If someone knows the anwers on 2 & 3 question, take me know, please.

#### GenericDAO interface:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T> {
    public boolean add(T t);
    public boolean update(int index, T t);
    public boolean remove(int index);
    public T getByIndex(int index);
    public List<T> getAll();

    // I want to add search method here if it's possible to search by any multiple object specs
}
```

#### GenericDAO implementation:

```
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {

    public Set<T> objects = new HashSet<T>();

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        if (t != null && !objects.contains(t))
            objects.add(t);

        return objects.contains(t);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(int index, T t) {
        if (index >= 0 && t != null) {
            if (objects.remove(getByIndex(index))) {
                objects.add(t);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean remove(int index) {
        Object obj = getByIndex(index);

        if (obj != null && objects.contains(obj))
            objects.remove(obj);

        return !objects.contains(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public T getByIndex(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < objects.size())
            return new ArrayList<T>(objects).get(index);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getAll() {
        return new ArrayList<T>(objects);
    }
}
```

#### EmployeeDAO interface:

```
public interface EmployeeDAO {

    // Some kind of specific functionality for employee

    public List<Employee> search(PersonalSpecs personalSpecs, EmployeeSpecs employeeSpecs);
}
```

#### EmployeeDAO implemenetation:

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Employee> implements EmployeeDAO {

    @Override
    public List<Employee> search(PersonalSpecs personalSpecs, EmployeeSpecs employeeSpecs) {
        if (personalSpecs != null || employeeSpecs != null) {
            for (Employee employee : getAll()) {
                if (employee.getPersonalSpecs().matches(personalSpecs, false) || employee.getEmployeeSpecs().matches(employeeSpecs))
                    add(employee);
            }
        }

        return getAll();
    }
}
```

#### CustomerDAO interface:

```
public interface CustomerDAO {

    // Some kind of specific functionality for customer

    public List<Customer> search(PersonalSpecs personalSpecs);
}
```

#### CustomerDAO implementation:

```
public class CustomerDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Customer> implements CustomerDAO {

    @Override
    public List<Customer> search(PersonalSpecs personalSpecs) {
        if (personalSpecs != null) {
            for (Customer customer : getAll()) {
                if (customer.getPersonalSpecs().matches(personalSpecs, false))
                    add(customer);
            }
        }

        return getAll();
    }
}
```

#### Employee class:

```
public class Employee {
    private PersonalSpecs personalSpecs;
    private EmployeeSpecs employeeSpecs;

    public Employee(PersonalSpecs personalSpecs, EmployeeSpecs employeeSpecs) {
        this.personalSpecs = personalSpecs;
        this.employeeSpecs = employeeSpecs;
    }

    public PersonalSpecs getPersonalSpecs() {
        return personalSpecs;
    }

    public void setPersonalSpecs(PersonalSpecs personalSpecs) {
        this.personalSpecs = personalSpecs;
    }

    public EmployeeSpecs getEmployeeSpecs() {
        return employeeSpecs;
    }

    public void setEmployeeSpecs(EmployeeSpecs employeeSpecs) {
        this.employeeSpecs = employeeSpecs;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.personalSpecs.getName().hashCode() + this.personalSpecs.getSurname().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((Employee) obj).personalSpecs.getName().equals(this.personalSpecs.getName()) && ((Employee) obj).personalSpecs.getSurname().equals(this.personalSpecs.getSurname());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hash: " +
                hashCode() +
                " - Employee{\n" +
                personalSpecs +
                "\n" +
                employeeSpecs +
                '}';
    }

}
```

#### Customer class:

```
public class Customer {
    private PersonalSpecs personalSpecs;
    private int bonus;

    public Customer(PersonalSpecs personalSpecs) {
        this.personalSpecs = personalSpecs;
    }

    public Customer(PersonalSpecs personalSpecs, int bonus) {
        this.personalSpecs = personalSpecs;
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    public PersonalSpecs getPersonalSpecs() {
        return personalSpecs;
    }

    public void setPersonalSpecs(PersonalSpecs personalSpecs) {
        this.personalSpecs = personalSpecs;
    }

    public int getBonus() {
        return bonus;
    }

    public void setBonus(int bonus) {
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.personalSpecs.getName().hashCode() + this.personalSpecs.getSurname().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((Customer) obj).personalSpecs.getName().equals(this.personalSpecs.getName()) && ((Customer) obj).personalSpecs.getSurname().equals(this.personalSpecs.getSurname());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer: " +
                personalSpecs +
                ", bonus=" + bonus;
    }
}
```

#### EmployeeSpecs class:

```
public class EmployeeSpecs {
    private EmployeeType type;
    private String position;
    private Date start;

    public enum EmployeeType {
        CONTRACTOR,
        FULLTIME
    }

    public EmployeeSpecs(EmployeeType type, String position) {
        this.type = type;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public EmployeeType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(EmployeeType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Date getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(Date start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public boolean matches(Object obj) {
        EmployeeSpecs employeeSpecs = (EmployeeSpecs) obj;
        if (employeeSpecs != null) {
            if ((employeeSpecs.getType() != null && employeeSpecs.getType().equals(type)) ||
                    (employeeSpecs.getPosition() != null && !employeeSpecs.getPosition().isEmpty() && employeeSpecs.getPosition().equals(position)) ||
                    (employeeSpecs.getStart() != null && employeeSpecs.getStart().equals(start)))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" +
                "type=" + type +
                ", position='" + position + '\'' +
                ", start=" + start +
                ']';
    }
}
```

#### PersonalSpecs class:

```
public class PersonalSpecs {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Sex sex;
    private int age;

    public enum Sex {MALE, FEMALE}

    public PersonalSpecs(String name, String surname, Sex sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public PersonalSpecs(String name, String surname, Sex sex, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Sex getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(Sex sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean matches(Object obj, boolean strict) {
        PersonalSpecs personalSpecs = (PersonalSpecs) obj;
        if (personalSpecs != null) {
            if (strict)
                // Check matches only by full name
                return (personalSpecs.getName() != null && !personalSpecs.getName().isEmpty() && personalSpecs.getName().equals(name)) &&
                        (personalSpecs.getSurname() != null && !personalSpecs.getSurname().isEmpty() && personalSpecs.getSurname().equals(surname));
            else
                // Check any matches
                return (personalSpecs.getName() != null && !personalSpecs.getName().isEmpty() && personalSpecs.getName().equals(name)) ||
                        (personalSpecs.getSurname() != null && !personalSpecs.getSurname().isEmpty() && personalSpecs.getSurname().equals(surname)) ||
                        (personalSpecs.getSex() != null && personalSpecs.getSex().equals(sex)) ||
                        (personalSpecs.getAge() != 0 && personalSpecs.getAge() == age);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", sex=" + sex +
                ", age=" + age +
                ']';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is that you need, and how that compares to the code you have at the moment. Does your code produce the expected result? What exactly do you think is bad about your current approach?

Comment: I think you are looking for a approach like the one I had used http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36519/generic-dao-written-in-java. Have a look. It might give you some idea.

Answer (score 4):

One generic (pun unintended) suggestion: Use braces `{ }` for your `if` statements to ensure you do not accidentally introduce bugs, because it makes the presentation clearer.

**Minor points:**

1. You can compare `enums` by `==`, e.g. `employeeSpecs.getType() == type`.
2. Casting of `obj` in your `matches()` method is potentially unsafe and may/will throw `ClassCastException`s if you accidentally pass in the wrong object type.

**Major points:**

1. `hashCode()` computation usually does not simply add the hash codes from multiple fields, especially in your case where a `Person` with the name and surname `John, Doe` will have the same hashcode as `Doe, John`. If you are on Java 7, you can consider [`Objects.hash(Object... values`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29) instead. In fact, if you look at its implementation, the code goes something like this:

   ```
   result = 1;
   for (Object element : values) {
       result = 31 * result + (element == null ? 0 : element.hashCode());
   }
   return result;
   ```
2. You may want to re-visit the meaning of the `boolean` return type from your `add()` and `remove()` methods in `GenericDaoImpl`. Using the `add()` method for example, what happens when the data store `objects` already contain the incoming object `t`? Do you still want the method to return `true`, i.e. `t` is already present, or return `false`, because strictly speaking the `add()` operation isn't successful as `objects` is not modified at all? In your current implementation, you can consult the Javadoc for [`Set.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29):

> Returns:
>       true if this set did not already contain the specified element

Or more generically speaking, look at [`Collection.add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29).

> Returns:
>       true if this collection changed as a result of the call

edit:

One clarification regarding my final point above: I'm quoting the Javadocs from the `Collections` classes primarily because you are using a `Set` currently for your "persistence". Even if you are going to replace it with a database back-end and JDBC APIs that do not necessarily return `boolean` datatypes, it's worthwhile to consider what is the most suitable return value *you need* from your own APIs. Perhaps you discover that most of your use cases are just to check again whether the input object for `add` and `remove` are persisted or not, and therefore the original implementation will still make sense (you'll want to document it properly too).

Looking at your new changes...

```
public boolean remove(int index);
public boolean remove(T t);
```

These two implementations are pretty much the same, you can consider passing `getByIndex(index)` within the `remove(int index)` method to the `remove(T t)` method to reduce code duplication. :)

I also don't think your `getByIndex()` implementation is doing what you think... ultimately, there is still one instance of your persisted objects in `objects`. If you are thinking of returning immutable copies of your `Customer` or `Employee` objects, then you actually have a bit more work to do.

I'm not sure what your two new `updateSpecs` methods are doing in your `EmployeeDAO` class, care to explain? *Actually, it'll be better if you can submit a new question for further significant changes, so that the history and answers for this question can be largely consistent...*

Finally, onto your original question about searching for different generic types right within your `GenericDAOImpl` class: I don't think that's possible, and this is where I hope other Java experts can offer their advice or solution on this...

Comment: Thank you very much, that is valuable marks for me and I have already fixed them. But I am still worry about `search()` method. How to deal with this specs in `GenericDAO`, is it possible to generify it somehow? Otherwise, I should implement specific `search()` method for each `EmployeeDAOImpl` and `CustomerDAOImpl`? Do you have any ideas on this point?

Comment: Thanks, and one question concerning immutable objects in getByIndex(). I didn't understand exactly how to realize it. I read about clone() method for this purpose but it seems it isn't good practice to use it. Also I saw that someone just create a new Collection and add all objects from one colletion to another, is it corect way? How it can be achieved the best way? As for updateSpecs, I have add them as a workaround due to I don't see any way to generify specs in GenericDAOImpl.

Comment: However, just to know, it is a good idea to separate PersonalSpecs from Personal(the same thing for Employee class) class at whole?

Comment: Creating a new `Collection` only allows you to modify the contents of the copy, say by adding, removing or even re-ordering (if supported) elements without affecting the original `Collection`. However, if you get an element from either `Collection`s, both having the same reference to it, changing the element's state will be reflected in both `Collection`s. Given the latest revision to your question, I think we can continue the review in a new question that contains your changes... :)

Comment: I have continued to review my latest changes -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57755/base-generic-dao-optimizations